# Dynamically change tags background color

Tags: jquery, tags

I m using
https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager

I used tag manager for email. I want to change the tags background if email is not registered with system. I did ajax code for checking user. Now i want to change tags background if "data==0"(refer from below code).

My code:

```
jQuery('.attendees').tagsManager({
            prefilled: [user_email],
            hiddenTagListName: 'attendee',
            delimiters: [32, 44, 13, 9], // comma, space (ASCII chars)
            blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
            blinkBGColor_2: '#c5eefa',
            validator: function (value) {
                 var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

            $.ajax({
                    url: 'CheckUserExits',
                    type: 'GET',

                    data: {email: value},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        alert($(this).val());
                        if(data==0) 
                            $(this).addClass('tm-tag tm-tag-error');

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }

                });
                 return emailReg.test(value);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(data==0) //also check data first
{   alert("executed");
    $(this).attr('style', 'Background-color:green;');               
}
```